# Sustaining node failure in Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

If we have 3 brokers in a cluster with replication factor as 3, how many nodes failure can it sustain. If my understanding is correct, then there will be a leader and 2 followers on 2 brokers. So, does it mean that, the cluster can sustain 2 node failure? I am not sure though

Answer (score 0):

Replication of 3 means you can sustain losing both followers. All produce and consume requests can continue from the leader partition, however, for consumers, you also need to consider the leader for `_consumer_offsets` topic since if that topic becomes unavailable, then group offset tracking will stop working